# Magento 2 Backend different node

Tags: magento2, backend

I would like to setup the backend of my Magento 2 install on a different server, can you guide me with the steps ?

Answer (score 2):

**Not too simple to explain:**

1. There is not a simple answer to your question.
2. There are several ways to do it depending on where you placed you MySQL server, how you configured your environment and what Magento2 you have (CE/EE).

**The quick and dirty way is:**

Just install a 2nd Magento on a different machine and point it to the same MySQL as the frontend.
Use the 2nd machine for backend only.

**NOTE:** It is not the best option you have (expecially on EE), but it will work.

Comment: Hi, thanks you very much for your answers. I have a CE Edition. I have 3 servers : 1 front, 1 back and 1 BDD. I tried what you propose, but my Backend is redirecting to the frond. So I changed the param "Use custom admin url" and I set the server backend URL. Now my backend is not accessible from the front but still not accesible from the back too

Comment: You are welcome. Pls mark as correct answer if you think is ok

Comment: I send the message without finishing it. Can you see my details ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just define a multiwebsite environment. Put the frontend on the "real domain" and punt the backend to a subdomain. Otherwise create a ProxyPass directive on you frontend to redirect admin requests to back

Comment: Hi @Riccardo, I don't understand. I have 3 different servers and front and back are connected to the same bdd. I don"t understand how to configure the multi website environnement. Thanks

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

Comment: @Cochou https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/802#issuecomment-275545778 this solution works perfectly.